# Selecting columns from two tables Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a join query between tables(t1,t2) that needs to select some columns from BOTH tables .

Doing something like :

```
t1::find()->select("t1.id , t2.id")->innerJoin('t2 ...)
```

but, it doesn't retrieve t2.id .

How to do it in Yii ?

The corresponding MySql query :

```
select t1.id , t2.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an `ActiveRecord` you either need the `id` as a property on the AR or use `asArray`.

e.g.

```
t1::find()->select("t1.id , t2.id")->innerJoin('t2 ...')->asArray()->...
```